# Is there anyway to change background-image based on button selected?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone knew how I can change background images based on the specific ID that the user selects. I am essentially making a game where people select the right option and the images change based on the right answer/wrong answer. I tried to create a div on my HTML but I have no clue what I would do for the javascript because of my set system already.

Heres my code:
https://codepen.io/tdodia/pen/yLgMgRO

```
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')
let state = {}
```

Also sorry, I had no real clue how to give correct context on the code so
i think the best bet is to look at the codepen link.

Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tay.jis, Have made a few changes ->

You need to dynamically change the image source on button click, that will do the trick for you.

```
document.getElementById('myImage').src = textNodes[textNodeIndex]['url']
```

Also,

add a new key "url" in your object with the image you want.

Check the implementation->
https://codepen.io/raishavhanspal/pen/PoWmGVP

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I was having a hard time linking the images to the textnodes that i created because this was the first time that I really used them. Was def confusing myself.